# CSS - responsive flex layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a simple flex layout with 4 blocks in a row.

at 500px I want to change the layout to 2 rows with the blocks being 50% of the width.

How do I do this with flex.

```css
*{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul{
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

li{
  /*flex-grow: 1;*/
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 8px;
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 500px){
  ul{
    /*flex-wrap: wrap;*/
  }
  li{
    background: yellow;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="one">One</li>
  <li class="two">Two</li>
  <li class="three">Three</li>
  <li class="three">Four</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you using `Bootstrap 4` ? Have you used *Media Queries* before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is `flex-basis`.

You also have some padding and margins that might screw up the layout a little. I would suggest setting these on an inner child of the `li`.

```
*{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul{
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

li{
  /*flex-grow: 1;*/
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 500px){
  ul{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  li{
    background: yellow;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `flex: 1 25%;` in normal view and `flex: 2 50%;` in `500px` port view. You can check in my code snippet bellow:

```css
*{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

li{
  flex: 1 25%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (max-width: 500px){
  li{
    background: yellow;
    flex: 2 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="one">One</li>
  <li class="two">Two</li>
  <li class="three">Three</li>
  <li class="three">Four</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works try this

```
*{
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul{
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

li{
  /*flex-grow: 1;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 8px;
  list-style: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
  ul{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
  }

  li{
    background: yellow;
    flex:  42%;
    padding: 2%;
  }
}   




    <ul>
      <li class="one">One</li>
      <li class="two">Two</li>
      <li class="three">Three</li>
      <li class="three">Four</li>
    </ul>
```